# How to display the image in the correct format

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the follwing XSLT code:

```
             <xsl:template match="data[@key='picture']"> 
               <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(picture, '.') "/>
               <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(picture, '.') "/>
            </xsl:template>
```

as well as:

```
<data key="picture" value="the-parlotones.jpg" />
```

I would like to have the following XML output:

```
<photo format="jpg">pascal-pierce</photo>
```

What should I add to get the desired output?

Comment: Please learn about the tag system of this site - all but one of your tags were completely irrelevant. Then, please show a complete input XML, and a complete XSLT stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the desired output should be `<photo format="jpg">the-parlotones</photo>` for the input in the question and not `<photo format="jpg">pascal-pierce</photo>`, you should change the template as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="data[@key='picture']">
  <photo format="{substring-after(@value, '.')}">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@value, '.') "/>
  </photo>
</xsl:template>
```

In your input `<data key="picture" value="the-parlotones.jpg" />`
`the-parlotones.jpg` is the value of the attribute `value`, so using `<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(picture, '.') "/>` won't work as `picture` is just the value of the attribute `key` of the element `data`.